what are the differences and uses of functions and customwidgets of flutter
In Flutter development, functions and widgets serve different purposes but are both crucial for building UI components and managing application logic.I want to know about how those 2 are used correctly in flutter development process
I need to clear answer with examples

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo

To know the difference between the helperMethod and the CustomWidget you first need to understand how the setState works.
Simply when you use the setState in your widget it is looking for the nearest build method and it rebuilding it.
So when you use helperMethod you just separate a piece of code in a method but when you setState part of your Widget (which is helperMethod) it rebuild the whole Widget.
But when you use CustomWidget you create a new pranch in the WidgetTree so if you setState part of your Widget (which is the CustomWidget) it will rebuild the specific part, that's cuz CustomWidget has it's own build method
Here's an Example :

class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  bool isCahnged = false;
  Color? color = Colors.cyan[100];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("Item $i"),
                tileColor: Colors.purple[100],
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          Center(
            child: const CustomWidget(), // You can use buildHelperMethod() also
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildHelperMethod() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: context.screenHeight * .3,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            "HelperMethod vs CustomWidget",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const Text(
            "This will show you the difference between helperMethod && customWidget",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  isCahnged = !isCahnged;
                  if (isCahnged) {
                    color = Colors.cyan[100]!;
                  } else {
                    color = Colors.brown[100]!;
                  }
                },
              );
            },
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const Text("Show Me"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomWidget> createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  Color? color = Colors.cyan[100];
  bool isCahnged = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: context.screenHeight * .3,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            "HelperMethod vs CustomWidget",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const Text(
            "This will show you the diffrence between helperMethod && customWidget",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  isCahnged = !isCahnged;
                  if (isCahnged) {
                    color = Colors.cyan[100]!;
                  } else {
                    color = Colors.brown[100]!;
                  }
                },
              );
            },
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const Text("Show Me"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


As you can see if you use buildHelperMethod() it will make rebuild to :
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("Item $i"),
                tileColor: Colors.purple[100],
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),

which is not necessary , because there is nothing will change in it
on the other hand if you use CustomWidget it will just to the needed part only and this part :
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("Item $i"),
                tileColor: Colors.purple[100],
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),

will NOT rebuild cuz it's separated from the CustomWidget build.
So We can say that the CusomWidget wins !!!
It will be different if you use a specific StateManageMent like Provider ..... ,etc
